# Limit UIGestureRecognizer to special area

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

is there a way to limit a UIGestureRecognizer to a special area of a view? For example the top and bottom 100px of a view?

Thanks in advance,
Dom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add transparent views above your primary view and add UIGestureRecognizers to those views.

Comment: Ah, great – that's a good idea and much easier than my approach to analyze where the taps took place using their position. Thanks alot!