# How to limit DragGesture area

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm having a little "bug" where my marker goes outside the area of the item it's been dragged on. I have a `.gesture` modifier on my image with frame and a fixed position. When you tap on it, it shows a circle (marker) where you've tapped. If I press the image then drag to the bottom of screen and release, the marker shows where I release my thumb/finger. I dont want that. It should never pass the image.

```swift
@State private var location = CGPoint.zero
@State private var showMarker = false

// body uses a ScrollView, without a NavigationView
// Not shown here
ZStack {
    Image("some-image")
        .resizable()
        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: 300, alignment: .top)
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        // I had to fiddle with the y cords just to get it below the navigationbar.
        .position(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2, y: 155)
        // DragGesture could be the culprit
        // But looking at the api, I see nothing useful like
        // a maximumDistance?
        .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0).onEnded { value in
            print(value)
            self.location = value.location
            self.showMarker = true
        }).padding(.bottom)
    
        if showMarker {
            Circle().foregroundColor(.red)
                .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                .position(self.location)
        }
    
    // Here we can loop the saved positions as markers
    //....   
}

VStack(...}
```

[image]

**Image looks funny but shows the dot goes pass the drawing (image)**

I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373016/limit-uigesturerecognizer-to-special-area), but this was many moons ago and I do not understand the answer where I'd convert to SwiftUI. How to prevent the marker from passing the height of the image?

Comment: Can you add gif file for this bug?

Comment: Hola @RajaKishan, I've made the edit with an online converter.